# Present UIImagePickerController to launch camera to take image but camera has black preview or glitches on iPhone 5 with iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-5

In my application, I am taking images by presenting UIImagePickerController, and after taking image uploading it to server on multiple background threads using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)`, while the image is uploading to server,I can take another image as the UI is not blocked while the previous image is being uploaded.It is working absolutely fine on iPhone 4S with iOS 7, but when I checked my application on iPhone 5, it shows me black preview camera screen or glitches in the camera if the previous image is being uploaded in the background.When I removed these background threads for image uploading, the camera preview is working fine.But I have to upload the images on background threads without freezing the UI and it is working fine on iPhone 4S.Could anyone help me with this? Is it a device specific bug or am I doing anything wrong?[image]

Comment: could you try another model of iPhone 5? maybe it's connected with particular device...

Comment: did you find out what's causing the problem?

Comment: Yea it was a particular device issue, I tested my application on another iPhone 5 and it was working fine, then I reset the device and now it is working on my device as well..